# How to merge an array of size M into another array of size 2M

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, big-o, mergesort

I got this question in an online code challenge. I needed to merge two sorted arrays, one of size `M` with `M` elements into another one, with `M` elements and capacity `2M`. I provided the following solution:

```
class ArraysSorting {

/**
 * Function to move elements at the end of array
 * 
 * @param bigger array
 */
void moveToEnd(int bigger[]) {
    int i = 0, j = bigger.length - 1;
    for (i = bigger.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (bigger[i] != 0) {
            bigger[j] = bigger[i];
            j--;
        }
}

/**
 * Merges array smaller array of size M into bigger array of size 2M
 * @param bigger array
 * @param smaller array
 */
void merge(int bigger[], int smaller[]) {
    moveToEnd(bigger);
    int i = smaller.length;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while (k < (bigger.length)) {
        if ((i < (bigger.length) && bigger[i] <= smaller[j]) || (j == smaller.length)) {
            bigger[k] = bigger[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        } else {
            bigger[k] = smaller[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

The Time Complexity: `O(2M)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't beat linear time because you have to at least scan all the `2M` elements, so that's the best you can ever get.

In practice though, you can optimize it a little further. There's no need to shift the elements of `bigger` towards the end; just write the results right-to-left rather than left-to-right (and of course, you'll need to invert the comparison, at any step you'll want to select the largest element rather than the smallest).

Also, this is not good:

```
if ((i < (bigger.length) && bigger[i] <= smaller[j]) || (j == smaller.length)) {
    /* ... */
}
```

You should test `j == smaller.length` before accessing `smaller[j]`; the code as is will possibly access out of bounds positions in `smaller`. Do this instead:

```
if ((j == smaller.length) || (i < (bigger.length) && bigger[i] <= smaller[j])) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Overall, I do think you can make the code simpler, here's something that in my opinion is easier to read because the `if` conditions are smaller and easier to understand (it also approaches the traditional way in which you merge two arrays and avoids the extra `O(M)` work of shifting the elements to the back):

```
void merge(int bigger[], size_t bigger_len, int smaller[], size_t smaller_len) {
    ssize_t smaller_i, bigger_i, idx;

    if (smaller_len == 0)
        return;

    smaller_i = smaller_len-1;

    if (bigger_len == 0)
        bigger_i = -1;
    else
        bigger_i = bigger_len-1;

    idx = bigger_len+smaller_len-1;

    while (smaller_i >= 0 && bigger_i >= 0) {
        if (bigger[bigger_i] > smaller[smaller_i]) {
            bigger[idx] = bigger[bigger_i];
            bigger_i--;
        }
        else {
            bigger[idx] = smaller[smaller_i];
            smaller_i--;
        }
        idx--;
    }

    while (smaller_i >= 0) {
        bigger[idx] = smaller[smaller_i];
        smaller_i--;
        idx--;
    }
}
```

It's easy to see that the first loop runs as long as a comparison between two elements in the different arrays is possible (rather than having the loop always run and use complicated `if` tests inside). Also note that since output is being written to `bigger`, once the first loop terminates, we only need to make sure that the rest (if any) of `smaller` that is left is copied over to `bigger`. The code is in C, but it's pretty much the same in Java. `bigger_len` and `smaller_len` are the number of elements in `bigger` and in `smaller`; it is assumed that `bigger` has enough space for `bigger_len+smaller_len` elements. The initial `if` tests to assign to `smaller_i` and `bigger_i` are necessary to handle edge cases where subtracting 1 would overflow the (unsigned) range of `size_t`; they are unnecessary in Java since Java doesn't have unsigned types (correct me if I'm wrong, I haven't done Java recently).

Time complexity remains `O(M)`.

Comment: Yes, there are no unsigned types in Java, you can use long instead of int :)